# A simple question on surjective map

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ a surjective map, where $X$ and $Y$ are two no empty set. 
Let $A\subseteq X$ be a subset no empty. Know that $g:=f_{|A}\colon A\to Y$ is also surjective.

Since $f$ is surjective $f(X)=Y$.

> **Question.** Can we say something about $g(A)$? That is $g(A)=Y$ or $g(A)\subseteq Y$?

If $g(A)\subseteq Y$, when we consider the restriction of a surjective function would it not be worthwhile to restrict the codomain also?

Thanks!

Comment: of course, $g(A)$ may be a proper subset of $Y$.

Comment: If $X$ (and hence, $Y$) has more than one element, this is false.

Comment: You assumed yourself, next to the definition of $g$, that $g$ is surjective, didn't you?

Comment: @Adam Latosiński I wrote something wrong, excuse me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you know that $g=f\restriction_A$ is also surjective, by definition this means $g[A]=f[A]=Y$.

In general (just knowing $A \subseteq X$) we know that $g[A]=f[A] \subseteq Y$ and that inclusion can easily be proper.

Again by definition, changing the codomain of $g$ so that $g=f\restriction A: A \to f[A]$ (defined by $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $X \in A$ of course) will make $g$ surjective again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I said an inaccuracy, because if $f$ is surjective, the restriction is not necessarily so. However, $f_{|A}\colon A\to f(A)$ it's surjective.